# SSAS Cube Grouping

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2008, ssas, ssas-2008

Hi I would like to disable grouping on my attributes.  Right now when I broswse my cube, all the attributes come as grouped and I have the expand/collapse option.  I want to see my data as a list. Thanks.

Right now:

A  5000

2000

Desired result:

A 5000

A 2000

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be browsing a hierarchy. 
Go to your dimension designer, look for it and check which attributes belong to it.
You may have to add these attributes to your cube to see the data the way you want

Comment: I am browsing two different dimensions that are realted to each other. Is there way to disable grouping?